# How to split the sparse matrix in Scipy?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm using `sklearn` to classify documents. But I got in trouble splitting the sparse matrix produced by `TfidfTransformer` which contains the corpus of both the train and the test data.

Here is part of my code:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
transformer = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2", use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=True)
matrix = transformer.fit_transform(vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus))
```

Here `corpus` is the direct combination of the train data and the test data(i.e. read the train data and then the test data)
and I want to split `matrix` to obtain `x_train` and the `x_test`.

`train_test_split()` cannot be used because it's stochastic
but I only want to split the matrix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two questions, 1) why don't you split your dataset file into separate train and test files and 2) can you explain what you mean by "`train_test_split()` cannot be used because it's stochastic [...]"?

Comment: 1) I want to get the tf-idf matrix on both train data and test data. 2) I mean `train_test_split()` is good but the data obtained by this method are randomly chosen.